# Set the quantity per product equal to value in input

Tags: commerce, ajax, 9

I'm using the [Commerce Ajax Add to Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_ajax_add_cart) module to add a product to my cart using AJAX. I guess I'll have to do that by creating a patch.

It's working fine, but I'd like to change how a product is added to the cart. For example, users add 4 times the same product in the cart. I've already made some changes so the by default, the quantity in my item cart is four. For now, if users click on *Add to cart, then the quantity will be added to the cart.

Instead of adding the quantity to the cart, I'd like to update the quantity. If users click on *Add to cart* and the quantity is five, instead of adding five to the quantity, the quantity for the product is five instead of nine.

After digging, I've found on commerce/modules/cart/src/Form/AddToCartForm.php `submitForm()`, which uses the following code.

```php
$this->entity = $this->cartManager->addOrderItem($cart, $order_item, $form_state->get(['settings', 'combine']));
```

I tried to remove the order item before adding the item (to "simulate" a quantity of 0) with this code.

```php
$this->cartManager->removeOrderItem($cart, $order_item);
```

I also tried by updating the order item cart.

```php
$this->entity = $this->cartManager->updateOrderItem($cart, $order_item, $form_state->get(['settings', 'combine']));
```

Neither of them gave the expected result.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I thought, I've ended up to create a patch for this feature.

Reminder, **this not a hotfix**, it's specific for my website.

```
diff --git a/modules/cart/src/CartManager.php b/modules/cart/src/CartManager.php
index 3b27ae77..b81db592 100644
--- a/modules/cart/src/CartManager.php
+++ b/modules/cart/src/CartManager.php
@@ -108,7 +108,8 @@ class CartManager implements CartManagerInterface {
       $matching_order_item = $this->orderItemMatcher->match($order_item, $cart->getItems());
     }
     if ($matching_order_item) {
-      $new_quantity = Calculator::add($matching_order_item->getQuantity(), $quantity);
+      //$new_quantity = Calculator::add($matching_order_item->getQuantity(), $quantity);
+      $new_quantity = $quantity; //TODO: voir si impact sur la partie menu ?
       $matching_order_item->setQuantity($new_quantity);
       $matching_order_item->save();
       $saved_order_item = $matching_order_item;
```